# recording to multiple locations

Tags: screen-casting

I am not 100% sure if this is on topic or not here but I think its the most relevant place to post this.

Are there any programs out there that record the screen but saves the output to multiple drive locations at once?

To elaborate, lets say I have 3 hard drives: `a)` `b)` and `c)`.

When it is saving from memory it will do the following...

- save 1/3 of the bytes to drive a)
- save 1/3 of the bytes to drive b)
- save 1/3 of the bytes to drive c)

But it does this concurrently.

Are there any screen recorders out there that can do this?

PC Specs:

- I7 clocked @ 6.5GHz
- Radeon HD 6490
- 32GB DDR5 RAM
- 2 * 3TH HDD's

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?  I don't think such a thing exists, since if someone wants RAID like functionality, they generally use RAID.  Implementing in in software like you describe would produce a lot of overhead and could possibly even result in slower performance.

Comment: I want it to act as a software RAID and when it outputs lets say to 3 different locations it will save byte 1 to first drive byte 2 to 2nd drive byte 3 to 3rd drive byte 4 to 1st drive ect I can't use raid because my computer doesn't support it

Comment: You likely are not going to get an advantage from this.  Encoding is a fairly CPU intensive task and taking up your CPU to do the file split is going to probably cause more issues than the extra bandwidth you'd pick up from the multiple file handles.  Are you currently experiencing problems with write performance and are you sure that you are disk I/O limited?

Comment: @AJHenderson Yes I am 100% sure that I am limited for disk I/O I wrote a program to do exactly what I wish to do but there is currently a bug within Java that causes the rendering step to cause OutOfMemoryExceptions due to Java's GarbageCollection thread not collecting old garbage from dead threads but the actual encoding and spliting the output to different locations causes so little of an overhead its not noticeable

Comment: Could you maybe post your machine specs/OS version? I really doubt that for a simple computer screen recording (that's what you're talking about, right?) a regular HDD lacks the performance. I'm not familiar with software that does what you want, but the specs might help people to answer the question.

Comment: @BartArondson ok added main specs

Answer (score 2):

You may find that it is easiest to use file system utilities rather than look for a recording application that writes multiple copies.

You could run mirrored filesystems, which will provide copied volumes, or simply set up scripts to copy individual files to multiple locations.

Comment: not exactly what i ment, I need to recorder to work as if im using RAID 0 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_0#RAID_0

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with the command-line, you could use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to [record your desktop](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg) and then use the [tee psuedo-muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepsuedo-muxer) to record copies to multiple locations. I haven't used this to record to separate hard-drives, but I'm not aware of any underlying issues that would prevent it.

A simple (Linux) example would be:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
-c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k \
-f tee "/path/to/output1.mp4|/path/to/output2.mp4|path/to/output3.mp4"
```

Comment: I need to recorder to work as if im using RAID 0 but using software not hardware en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_0#RAID_0

Comment: @JordanLeslieTrainor I don't know if that's possible, but you might have better luck asking a more generic 'emulating RAID 0 with software' question over on [superuser](http://superuser.com) or one of the other more technically-oriented SE sites